# ionic build android command returns an error at gradle.wrapper

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When i trying to use `ionic build android` in cli and it returns

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException
: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketI
mpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.ja
va:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocket
Impl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:1168)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConn
ection.java:1104)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:998)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLCo
nnection.java:1512)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1440)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more

C:\Users\TCYCAKMAK\simple\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\TCYCAKMAK\simple\platfo
rms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\TCYCAKMAK\simple\platforms\android
\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\TCYCAKMAK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

I installed everything like android sdk, ant etc. Also there is a proxy in my working area. I thought my problem stems from this but i didnt find any solution.

Comment: Maybe this answer can solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874564/ionic-build-android-error-when-download-gradle

Answer (score 0):

Do you have waited the end of the download of glade in command shell ?

If **true**

- Make a new project and test without modification

If your new project return the same message

- Make you sure you have correctly configured your var path environment.