# Ionic build failed with an exception

Tags: cordova, android-gradle-plugin, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, build.gradle

> I used proxy .I got error when I tru to run ionic build command.I put that error message follow.

```
D:\MyApp\myone>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\MyApp\myone\hooks\after_p
repare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\MyApp\myone
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\MyApp\myone\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat"
"
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\rajitha\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
Running: D:\MyApp\myone\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\MyApp\myon
e\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gr
adle/0.9.0/gradle-0.9.0.pom'.
         > repo1.maven.org

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 27.08 secs
```

> Is this error occur due to proxy.how can I solve that one.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gradle` is not yet supported in Phonegap. They are days away. But this could be an ionic issue. I don't know ionic.

Comment: found solution .use this command "cordova build android -- --ant"..further information use this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874564/ionic-build-android-error-when-download-gradle