# I'm getting a gradle error, how can I solve it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, configuration, project

I'm trying to do a console app in android studio, but when i execute the app it produces an error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Initialization script `/private/var/folders/3g/2b70v24d5cqggs_c_tmts3pw0000gn/T/MainApplication_main__.gradle' line: 20`
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project `:app Could not create task ':app:MainApplication.main()'.SourceSet with name 'main'` not found.
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.

Comment: try clean & rebuild ? try invalidate cache and restart ?

Comment: Check this out if it solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709946/failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-in-ionic

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to update gradle, in my case I was using JDK 13  and Gradle 5.x.x doesn't support it, so upgrading to 6.0.1 resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's using cache files coming with a different gradle version.

Usually the default gradle folder is *{user_home}/.gradle*

You should delete the content in that folder or specify another folder with the option --project-cache-dir

```
./gradlew --project-cache-dir .customGradleFolder
```