# Command:ionic build android is giving the error

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am fresher in ionic framework and Angular JS. I install ionic Framework

Using **ionic start myApp tabs** its working Properly. Then I apply this

The command to start project **ionic start myApp tabs** new Project is Created

Sucessfully then to runing this Project I used some Command:

1.cd myApp

2 ionic platform add android

These commands successfully run But When I hit this command:

**ionic build android**

When this is working on in run command:

Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

It is giving the Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostExcep
    tion: services.gradle.org
            at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
    essManager.java:78)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
    :178)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
            at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
    onnection.java:997)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
    ction.java:933)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
    .java:851)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
    nection.java:1301)
          nection.java:1301)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\broswire\myApp\p
latforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\broswire\myApp\platforms\andr
oid\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Comment: That error is telling you that it can't reach `services.gradle.org`, were you having issues with your internet connection, try again, or try to acces that site using your browser

Comment: Hello I found the answer from this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874564/ionic-build-android-error-when-download-gradle.  But the myApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js I did not find out the var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'; this in my  build.js