# IONIC Framework error code 1

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

IONIC Framework

Facebook & Google+ signin project

```
$ android build project

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

AND

```
    ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/satyam/ionic/aao-app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/satyam/ionic/aao-app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/satyam/ionic/aao-app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/satyam/ionic/aao-app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

If I removed plugin:
$ `cordova plugin remove phonegap-facebook-plugin`

This will build the project but I need to build with Google+ & Facebook

2) if you have any article or plugin which can directly help to access this.Please let me know.

Comment: may be this can solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874564/ionic-build-android-error-when-download-gradle