# ionic 2 build not working error build.gradle

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm developed app in ionic 2 framework i am try to build apk get following error

`ionic build android` get this following error

also i referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874564/ionic-build-android-error-when-download-gradle)  distributionUrl not available in build.js any other solution for this, how can i take build

```
    2=101, 23=115
 0=32, 1=85, 2=80, 3=45, 4=84, 5=79, 6=45, 7=68, 8=65, 9=84, 10=69
 0=13, 1=10, 2=58, 3=103, 4=101, 5=110, 6=101, 7=114, 8=97, 9=116, 10=101, 11=68
, 12=101, 13=98, 14=117, 15=103, 16=83, 17=111, 18=117, 19=114, 20=99, 21=101, 2
2=115
 0=32, 1=85, 2=80, 3=45, 4=84, 5=79, 6=45, 7=68, 8=65, 9=84, 10=69, 11=13, 12=10

 0=58, 1=99, 2=111, 3=109, 4=112, 5=105, 6=108, 7=101, 8=68, 9=101, 10=98, 11=11
7, 12=103, 13=74, 14=97, 15=118, 16=97, 17=87, 18=105, 19=116, 20=104, 21=74, 22
=97, 23=118, 24=97, 25=99
 0=32, 1=85, 2=80, 3=45, 4=84, 5=79, 6=45, 7=68, 8=65, 9=84, 10=69, 11=13, 12=10

 0=58, 1=99, 2=111, 3=109, 4=112, 5=105, 6=108, 7=101, 8=68, 9=101, 10=98, 11=11
7, 12=103, 13=78, 14=100, 15=107, 16=32, 17=85, 18=80, 19=45, 20=84, 21=79, 22=4
5, 23=68, 24=65, 25=84, 26=69, 27=13, 28=10
 0=58, 1=99, 2=111, 3=109, 4=112, 5=105, 6=108, 7=101, 8=68, 9=101, 10=98, 11=11
7, 12=103, 13=83, 14=111, 15=117, 16=114, 17=99, 18=101, 19=115
 0=32
 0=85, 1=80, 2=45, 3=84, 4=79, 5=45, 6=68, 7=65, 8=84, 9=69, 10=13, 11=10
 0=58, 1=116, 2=114, 3=97, 4=110, 5=115, 6=102, 7=111, 8=114, 9=109, 10=67, 11=1
08, 12=97, 13=115, 14=115, 15=101, 16=115, 17=87, 18=105, 19=116, 20=104, 21=68,
 22=101, 23=120, 24=70, 25=111, 26=114, 27=68, 28=101, 29=98, 30=117, 31=103
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupporte
d major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
1)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: com.android.dx.command.Main.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"

 0=32, 1=70, 2=65, 3=73, 4=76, 5=69, 6=68, 7=13, 8=10

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java.exe''
 finished with non-zero exit value 1


 0=13, 1=10, 2=66, 3=85, 4=73, 5=76, 6=68, 7=32, 8=70, 9=65, 10=73, 11=76, 12=69
, 13=68, 14=13, 15=10, 16=13, 17=10, 18=84, 19=111, 20=116, 21=97, 22=108, 23=32
, 24=116, 25=105, 26=109, 27=101, 28=58, 29=32, 30=55, 31=46, 32=51, 33=55, 34=4
9, 35=32, 36=115, 37=101, 38=99, 39=115, 40=13, 41=10
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"E:\workspace\ionicProject
s\mobilePay\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b E:\workspace\ionicProject
s\mobilePay\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.us
eDeprecatedNdk=true"


Caught exception:
 undefined

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

Comment: Which version of Ionic2 are you using?
Try installing the latest beta with `npm install -g ionic@beta` and then building again..

Comment: solved this issue i am using old jdk 1.6 after update to jdk 8 working fine