# Ionic - Error when trying to build an android project

Tags: gradle, ionic-framework

I'm currently learning Ionic and I am facing an issue when I try to build my project on an android platform.

When I run `ionic build android` I get the following error :

[image: ionic build android error]

I tried to add a `gradle.properties` file with proxy configuration but that didn't solve my problem.

Removing and recreating the Android platform didn't resolve the problem either.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

seems it is similar to [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception/66430/6) problem on ionic framework forum,

So it is recommended to  changed in the platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js file the distributionUrl like the following:
var distributionUrl = 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip';
(which was before)
var distributionUrl = 'http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip';

removing one '\' and changing from http to https solved the problem for me and it starts with donwloading

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
Tried this, and now I get this error  :

http://imgur.com/a/BWNfp

Comment: how about this solution on stack, how you tried it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874564/ionic-build-android-error-when-download-gradle