# ionic build android, stucks

Tags: cordova, ionic2

When I am trying to do `ionic build android` or install codova plugins on ionic 2 project, it is getting stuck on the part `Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 24"`.

Such as this:

```
>ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for android

Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android


ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\kiboy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1

JAVA_HOME=D:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_25

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).


Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 24".
```

This gets stuck for many hours.

Please help me.

Comment: did you have setup Android SDK/Gradle for the CLI path? looks like you may not have Android SDK 24

Comment: In fact, it s after I Downloaded Android SDK 24 that I run it. But I don't know if  that is related to it. Maybe do I have to change something to set it or I don't know? Before I used SDK 22, and I ve just download SDK 24 this morning I don't know if there is other options to do.

Comment: May be Re-adding the platform solve the issue, As you may have created project with SDK 22 and now you have SDK 24, the camera plugin is trying to install with new SDK 24, Did you download SDK 24 with the SDK manager right?

Comment: that s possible... I ll re add it then. I downloaded with Android studio.

Comment: Well, I am re-adding the platform and I got that error: 'Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.'

Comment: I tried to remove '.gradle' do that it downloads new version, but I got 'Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file'
And i m getting stucked there :(

Comment: I tried that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535930/cordova-build-gradle-error-while-opening-extracting-zip-file but still doesn t work!

Comment: So now do you have gradle install or not? if yes you may try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25009717/4557505 else you can try with ant instead of gradle, it's old build system but it may work

Comment: Nice, gradle works fine! But it still shows the android sdk 24 error whereas I ve already downloaded it.

Comment: Finally it works! I downgrade my cordova and installed all SDK 24 build-tools and now it works! Thank you very much @Sagar ! :)